# Three red dice. Sum of any two of them must be 2,3 or 4. What is the probability of that?

Tags: dice

I have a boardgame call Enemy Coast Ahead: The Dambusters in which enemy FLaK poses  a major problem.

Under some circumstances the game "AI" throws three instead of two dice and if the sum of any two of them is within a certain interval a hit is scored. Furthermore if doubles are rolled and that gives a hit the doubles are re-rolled. If that is a hit but not a re-roll the hit is score and then it stops. If that is a hit and a double hit is score and another re-roll follows.

For starters I'd just like to know the probability of the sum of the two dice being 2,3 or 4 when rolling three dice.

As I see it(and I have not idea whether I right): Dice 1,2 and 3, denoted A, B and C can roll a lethal combbination as AB, BC or AC.

At Flak Level 1 the lethal range is 2-4. That gives 1/36 + 2/36 + 3/36=6/36 =1/6 for a Hit.

Using three dice and combinations AB, DC and AC just one of them is enough for a hit so since OR goes into it we get 1/6 for each 1/6 + 1/6 + 1/6 = 1/2.

Best Regards
Peter

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ denote the event that $X_1+X_2\in\{2,3,4\}$.

Let $B$ denote the event that $X_1+X_3\in\{2,3,4\}$.

Let $C$ denote the event that $X_2+X_3\in\{2,3,4\}$.

With inclusion/exclusion and symmetry  we find:$$P(A\cup B\cup C)=3P(A)-3P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B\cap C)$$

Can you find these terms on RHS yourself?

If you calculate them correctly then your answer will be:$$3\cdot\frac6{36}-3\cdot\frac{14}{216}+\frac{11}{216}=\frac{77}{216}$$

Comment: Argh! How do I read that P(A.... ? Is that "Set Theory"?

Comment: Is there something I should read to understand that? Its some 35 years since I went to school.

Comment: You should read $P(A)=P(X_1+X_2\text { equals }2, 3\text{ or }4)$. Here $A$ is indeed a set. A subset of the outcome space actually. It concerns the underlying theory for probability. If you want to endeepen then go looking for "probability space" on e.g. Wikipedia.

Comment: If this goes too deep then you better accept the answer of lulu.

Comment: Why 3P? Because there are three numbers that interest us? Was 6 in 6/36 found by brute force or calculated and if yes how? I would like to understand.

Comment: Actually $P(A)+P (B)+P (C) $ but these probabilities are equal so the summation equals $3P (A) $. That is the use of what I call "symmetry " in my answer. Also google on the principle of inclusion /exclusion to get more sight on it.

Comment: Aha, and the 6/36, the 14/216 and the 11/216 ?

Comment: $P(A)=\frac6{36}$ because in $6$ of the $36$ equiprobable cases we have $X_1+X_2\in\{2,3,4\}$. $P(A\cap B)=\frac{14}{216}$ because in $14$ of the $216$ equiprobable cases with have $X_1+X_2\in\{2,3,4\}$ and $X_1+X_3\in\{2,3,4\}$. $P(A\cap B\cap C)=\frac{11}{216}$ because in $11$ of the $216$ equiprobable cases we have $X_1+X_2\in\{2,3,4\}$, $X_1+X_3\in\{2,3,4\}$ and $X_2+X_3\in\{2,3,4\}$.

Comment: Yes, ok but did you arrive at 6, 14 and 11 by manuel brute force counting?

Comment: Yes, that's just a matter of counting.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I don't think I can come up with further questions. Here in Denmark apparently there is a principle called PIE. ( The principle of inklusion and exclusion) I'm trying to understand it. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: You are very welcome. PIE is indeed what is applied in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add the probability of non-mutually exclusive events like that.  Suppose there were $10$ dice, so $\binom {10}2=45$ pairs.  Your method would give an answer greater than $1$.

Best here is brute force counting.

Counting the winning triples requires attention because there is a lot of overlap and because not all of them have the same number of permutations.

$6$ permutations:  $$\{1,2,3\}\quad \{1,2,4\}\quad\{1,2,5\}\quad\{1,2,6\}$$
$$\{1,3,4\}\quad \{1,3,5\}\quad\{1,3,6\}$$

$3$ permutations:  $$\{1,1,2\}\quad \{1,1,3\}\quad\{1,1,4\}\quad\{1,1,5\}\quad \{1,1,6\}$$
$$\{1,2,2\}\quad \{2,2,3\}\quad \{2,2,4\}\quad\{2,2,5\}\quad\{2,2,6\}$$
$$\{1,3,3\}$$

$1$ permutation:  $$\{1,1,1\}\quad \{2,2,2\}$$

Thus there are $$6\times 7+3\times 11+ 1\times 2=77$$  (ordered) winning triples.  As there are $6^3=216$ unrestricted ordered triples, the answer is $$\boxed {\frac {77}{216}=.35648}$$

CAUTION:  one problem with brute force enumeration is that it is quite error prone; it's hard to be sure you didn't miss a case or two.  Check my list carefully.  The first version of it left off two patterns and there might well be other errors that are still present.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Why is it called 6 permutations and 3 permutations?

Comment: @PeterLageri  I am writing down unordered triples and the $6,3,1$ refer to the number of  ways to order them.  $\{1,2,3\}$ for instance can be ordered $6$ ways, as $(1,2,3),(1,3,2),(2,1,3), (2,3,1), (3,1,2), (3,2,1)$.  While $\{1,1,2\}$ can only be ordered in $3$ ways and $\{1,1,1\}$ only has $1$ order.

Comment: It is correct, lulu (unless. ...:-)

Comment: @drhab  Seriously.  I thought it would be a simple enumeration...can't think when I last made so many blunders.  Glad to see the alternate computation you posted.

Comment: @Lulu. Thank you.

Comment: @drhab. Argh! How do I read that P(A.... ? Is that "Set Theory"?

Comment: Why 3P? Because there are three numbers that interest us? Was 6 in 6/36 found by brute force or calculated and if yes how? I would like to understand.

Comment: @PeterLageri  I think that comment must refer to the other posted solution, no?

Comment: @lulu. Yes, Sorry. I am disorderly

Answer (score 0):

Another way to brute force:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
D_1&D_2&D_3&Total\\
\hline
1&1-3&1-6&18\\
1&4-6&1-3&9\\
2&1-2&1-6&12\\
2&3-6&1-2&8\\
3&1&1-6&6\\
3&2&1-2&2\\
3&3-6&1&4\\
4-6&1&1-3&9\\
4-6&2&1-2&6\\
4-6&3&1&3\\
\hline
&&&77
\end{array}$$
Hence the required probability is $\frac{77}{6^3}$.

Comment: How do you calculate each linie?

Comment: Line 7 triples are: $(3,3,1);(3,4,1);(3,5,1);(3,6,1)$.

Comment: Last line are: $(4,3,1);(5,3,1);(6,3,1)$.